# Use id from parent table when importing child table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, import

I have a parent table, City, which has two columns id and name in my database, uploaded through '.csv' file, in this format:

id     | name
1      | Karachi
2      | Hyderabad

I have another Excel file which has data in the following format:

City     | Sector
Karachi  | Jamshed Town
Karachi  | Gulshan 13-D
Hyderabad| Sarfaraz Colony

I want to import data of Sectors but the columns city_id, sector from the city table and not the city name. How can I get the id from parent table. (Since the data is in thousands in a couple of files I don't prefer writing formulas in Excel)

Comment: Using vlookup in excel to map the city ids to the city names would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I would import the `city` table into excel and then use `vlookup()` function to map the cities' id to the sectors and import the sectors to mysql after that.

The other solution is to create another table in mysql that has city name and sector as fields, and import the sectors dataset into that table. You can use an `insert ... select ...` statement to populate the original sector table with city id and sector:

```
insert into sector (city_id, sector)
select id, sector from city
    inner join sector_with_c_name s2 on city.name=s2.city
```